# foreach() Invalid argument

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

Hello i keep getting this error Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on this loop below, i get two errors

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/xxx/xx.php on line 36
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xxx/xx.php:36) in /home/xxx/xx.php on line 100
> {"status":"success","count":0,"data":[]}

```
    <?php
require('../../../../wp-blog-header.php');
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
//$condition = isset($_REQUEST['condition']) ? $_REQUEST['condition'] : '';
//$condition = str_replace('\\','',$condition);
//$condition = '{"id":200,"items":[{"size":"m","color":"green"}]}';
$condition = isset($_REQUEST['condition'])? stripslashes( $_REQUEST['condition']) : '';
$search_condition = json_decode($condition,true);
/*
$search_condition = array(
'id'=>194,
'items'=>array(
    array(
        'size'=>'xl',
        'color'=>'blue',
    ),
)
);
*/


$id = $search_condition['id'];
$items= $search_condition['items'];

$condition_pair =array();
global $wpdb;
$table_posts = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';
$table_post_meta = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';
$string = 'product-'.$id.'-variation';
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("select * from   $table_posts  WHERE post_name LIKE '%$string%' ");

//echo "select * from   $table_posts p INNER JOIN $table_post_meta pm ON pm.post_id = p.ID WHERE p.post_name LIKE '%$string%'";exit;

$extra_attribute_records =  get_post_meta($id, '_product_attributes', TRUE);
$attribute_names = array();
foreach($extra_attribute_records as $key => $value)
{
$attribute_names[] = $key;

}

$list_product = array();
$i= 0;
foreach($posts as $post)
{
  $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));

$price = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_regular_price', TRUE);
$promotion = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sale_price', TRUE);
$weight = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_weight', TRUE);
$height = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_height', TRUE);
$width = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_width', TRUE);
$length = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_length', TRUE);
$quantity = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_stock', TRUE);
$quantity = (int)$quantity;
$sku = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sku', TRUE);
$stock_status = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_stock_status', TRUE);

$extra_attribute_records =  array();
foreach($attribute_names as $att_name)
{
    $extra_attribute_records[$att_name] = strtolower(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'attribute_'.$att_name, TRUE));
}

if(in_array($extra_attribute_records,$items))
{
    
    $title = get_the_title($id).' '.strtoupper(implode('/', $extra_attribute_records)).'';
    $arr = array(
        'id' => $post->ID,
        'title' => $title,
        'description' => get_post_field('post_content', $id),
        'excerpt' => get_post_field('post_excerpt', $id),
        'price' => $price,
        'currency' => get_woocommerce_currency(),
        'weight' => $weight,
        'sku' => $sku,
        'quantity' => $quantity,
        'featured' => 0,
        'mark_as_new' => $post->mark_as_new,
        'width' => $width,
        'height' => $height,
        'length' => $length,
        'sort_order' => $post->sort_order,
        'promotion_price'=>(int)$promotion,
        'thumbnail' => $image_url[0],
        'category_slug'=>$post->slug,
        'extra_attributes' => array(),//'$extra_attribute_records,
        'categories'=>get_the_product_category(),
        'stock_status'=>$stock_status,
        'post_date' => $post->post_date,
    );
    $list_product[] = $arr;
    $i++;
}

}


header('Content-type: text/json');
echo json_encode(
array(
    "status" => "success",
    'count' => $i,
    "data" => $list_product,
));
exit();
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Please post the _full_ error message...

Comment: Only the first, that is, the second is just a follow up.

Comment: And please tell us what `get_post_meta()` does, so post its code. Thanks.

Comment: Can we see the line numbers?

Comment: well, is `$extra_attribute_records` an array?

Comment: @arkascha i updated the warning message

Comment: `get_post_meta()` is a worpress function. @C.B If I remember correctly, you can't use `header()` in wordpress, because wp send headers before (and `wp-blog-header.php` print out). You have to use a corresponding wp header function. See documentation.

Comment: [`send_headers()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=send_headers&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-function&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-hook&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-class&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-method)

Comment: Yes it's wordpress, i have updated my whole code

Comment: I added “wordpress” tag. Maybe some wp expert can help you. But for me it's a bit complicated. i.e. what is the URL of page with code? `wp-blog-header.php` also load a template file, so if the template page contains html or any other output your code will ever fails, even if it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the issue please set the 3rd paramter in the `get_post_meta()` method to FALSE. Optionaly you could remove the 3rd param altogether as the defualt value is also FALSE. You should now get an array returned. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Replace the following line in the example:

```
$extra_attribute_records =  get_post_meta($id, '_product_attributes', TRUE);
```

With this line of code:

```
$extra_attribute_records =  get_post_meta($id, '_product_attributes', FALSE);
```

To prevent the "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error from happening if for any reason you where not to get an array back put an if statment around your foreach loop to check that `$extra_attribute_records` contains an array.

```
if(is_array($extra_attribute_records)){
    foreach($extra_attribute_records as $key => $value) { 
        $attribute_names[] = $key;
    }
}
```

The PHP error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" is being output to the page which is the reason why your headers are already sent by the time you get to "header('Content-type: text/json');". Fixing the above issue should hopfully allow you to send the Content-type header.

Comment: This tries to fix the symptom, not the cause.

Comment: I could not adivse on a fix to the cause as the problem lies within the `get_post_meta()` method, which we have not been supplied the code for.

Comment: Then maybe you should not have posted an "answer", since this does not answer the question?

Comment: I have now added my suggested fix to get the `get_post_meta()` method to return an array rather than an string.

Comment: @C.B I have now updated my answer which should get `get_post_meta` to return an array.

Comment: This IS the right answer, however you do NOT have to pass in `false` - that's the default value.